# Why am I getting an IndentationError when my code is properly indented?

Tags: python

Below is my entire code. When trying to execute it, I keep getting the error message

```
File "/Users/thomas/prac.py", line 15
  elif choice == "1":
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Now I'm sure my indenting is right (I didn't mix tabs and spaces!) but I don't know why this isn't working:

```
keepProgramRunning = True
while keepProgramRunning:
    print "Pleases choose an option: "
    print "0"
    print "1"

    choice = raw_input()

    if choice == "0":
        #do something
    elif choice == "1":
        print "Bye"
        keepProgramRunning = False
    else:
        print "try again"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Small aside: Instead of using a sentinel variable in a `while` loop, it's easier to do `while True:` and then, in the `elif choice == "!":` block, do a `break` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A comment isn't enough to be considered an indentation. If you want to have an empty block then you need to use the `pass` statement.

Comment: Although it is common practice to use {pass} it is not true that you need to use the {pass} statement. In Cpython, a string also surfices, as such; {"do something"} instead of {#do something}. You can also do an expression like any one of True, False, None or even just a number. But {pass} is best.

Comment: thank you so much, i just didn't understand what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can't have empty if statement. Python expects something to reside in there, and if you really don't need to put anything you can put pass in there.

But why having if statement if you don't have anything to do in it.

Comment: just trying to get the menu to display then i was going to add the functionality, thanks for the help